# Error ORA-22828 while passing clob data into oracle stored proc using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, clob, ojdbc

I am trying to send CLOB data into a stored proc using JDBC. I am using oracle database 11g and ojdbc6.jar for driver. I am not able to send the data as it is greater than 32kb. I had tried various ways to send the data:

1. Using Clob object
2. Using characterStream

These all did not work for me.
I got the following error:
ORA-22828: input pattern or replacement parameters exceed 32K size limit

Is there some way to pass large data into oracle stored proc using jdbc(java), which may scale to 1MB.
Code used is as follows:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null;

String formedStr = "{CALL MAIL_PROC(?)}";
//Preparing statement
cstmt = con.prepareCall(formedStr);
cstmt.setCharacterStream(1, new StringReader(info.getContent()), info.getContent().length());
cstmt.execute();
```

Comment: CLOB can be up to 2,147,483,647 characters, given your error stating "32K size limit" - talk to your DBA & ask that the table is redesigned and the length limit is increased. Or truncate your data.

Comment: Please show your code, table schema, etc.

Comment: I am not at all inserting data into a table. I am just passing data to stored proc which have only one input variable of CLOB type.

Comment: @Dave 32k is the limit of a varchar in PL/SQL. I doubt that the table is the limiting factor.

Comment: Try `setString()` - more recent driver versions (11.x - you didn't specify _your_ version) should handle that correctly. Another possibility is that the stored procedure somehow converts the `CLOB` to a `VARCHAR` and while doing that, the error is thrown inside the procedure, not when passing the value.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I had added the code sample, since I am not interacting with any tables inside proc so have basically no schema to share.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I tried that also. That was not working.

Comment: It started working, I do not know if it caused the problem. But in the string I was adding a next line character. I removed that and it started working. I have no idea if next line can cause a problem.

Comment: @john0609 The internet is lacking good examples on how to pass CLOB values larger than 32k. If you would please answer your own question with working code you'll get an upvote from me!

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: I had added ways we can use to pass CLOB data using JDBC. There is no issue with ojdbc jar but I guess next line marker was making some difference.

Answer (score 2):

There was issue with the String object that I passed in as clob. It had a next line (\r\n) in it. When I removed it, call was going well.
I had used three types of calls to pass clob object and all are working fine now:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null;

String formedStr = "{CALL MAIL_PROC(?)}";

cstmt = con.prepareCall(formedStr);

//Option 1:
cstmt.setCharacterStream(1, new StringReader(info.getContent()), info.getContent().length());

//Option 2:
cstmt.setString(1, info.getContent());

//Option 3:
Clob stmtClob = con.createClob();
stmtClon.setString(1,info.getContent())
cstmt.setClob(1,stmtClob);

cstmt.execute();
```